# How does a java client access an integer array from a java RESTful web service

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am reframing my own question at : [Returning a primitive array through REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785920/returning-a-primitive-array-from-a-restful-web-service-method)

I am using Jersey, and I am unable to understand what codes/annotations should be added at both server and client ends to return an "array" of primitives (strings, integers, anything). I can do this very easily in SOAP...isnt there some easy way out in REST ? I got some complex ways of doing this here :
[how-to-serialize-java-primitives-using-jersey-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629544/how-to-serialize-java-primitives-using-jersey-rest)

A piece of code (both server and client) would be appreciated a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the primitive array in a JAXB annotated object.  Jersey will use the built-in `MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter`

E.g.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public IntArray {

 private int[] ints;

 public IntArray() {}

 public IntArray(int[] ints) {
  this.ints = ints;
 }

 public int[] getInts() {
  return ints; 
 } 
 ...
}
```

On the server side:

```
@Path("ints")
public class TestResource {

 @GET
 @Produces("application/xml")
 public Response get() {
  int[] ints = {1, 2, 3};
  IntArray intArray = new IntArray(ints);
  return Response.ok(intArray).build();
 } 
}
```

On the client side:

```
Client client = new Client();
WebResource wr = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/service");
IntArray intArray = wr.path("/ints").get(IntArray.class);
int[] ints = intArray.getInts();
```

Try something like that.  I didn't test the code, so hopefully it works.

Comment: Thanks reverendgreen...but this is not working. I am getting a null value at the client side :(

Comment: Strange... I just tested the code and it works great.  Can you show a bit of your code? Perhaps myself or someone else can spot the error.

Comment: Try your request URI in a browser; if you don't see the expected response, then it's a problem on the server side.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I guess my code was not working as I avoided using @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) !